# Login with Facebook App confuse

Tags: facebook, api

I have built an Android game with register using Facebook feature .
And I have built a forum website for this game which make users login to the forum with the Facebook account which they registered in the android game.
The question is :
When i get a user profile in the Graph API tool it retrieves a different user id in the forum than the user id from the android game.

I have found a solution is to connect both game and forum with same Facebook app but we must set one redirect URL for the both game and app, but as you know we cant !

Any help guys to solve the problem :)
Thanks alot

Note: I have used this [oneall.com](http://oneall.com) service to make login in forum website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called "App Scoped ID", each user will get a different ID per App. If you need to match users between different Apps, use the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business